# Excel formulas for pulling word strings

Tags: excel

Is there a formula that can extract the "Cleaner Volume:24 fl oz (0.8 quart)" out of this string?

**General Information**

---

Manufacturer:The Clorox Company
Manufacturer Part Number:97326CT
Manufacturer Website Address:http://www.thecloroxcompany.com
Brand Name:Pine-Sol
Product Name:All Purpose Multi-Surface Cleaner
Marketing Information:

With Pine-Sol All Purpose Cleaner, you only need one cleaner to fight dirt, grime and grease. It is EPA-registered to disinfect and kill 99 percent of germs on most surfaces throughout your home or office. All-purpose cleaner gives you four times the cleaning action and a great, long-lasting scent. It deodorizes and wipes out odor-causing bacteria, leaving a pleasant pine scent. This concentrated cleaner can tackle any challenge by simply mixing with water at different strengths to adjust your cleaning power each time, unlike premixed cleaners. All-purpose cleaner allows safe use on most hard, nonporous surfaces, including finished hardwood, ceramic tile, linoleum and plastic, and leaves no sticky residue. Pine-Sol Original Pine can also be used to freshen laundry.

Packaged Quantity:12 / Carton
Product Type:Multi-Surface Cleaner
**Product Information**

---

Cleaner Volume:24 fl oz (0.8 quart)
Scent:Original
Recommended Use:

- Stain Remover
- Bacteria Remover
- Odor Remover
- Dirt Remover
- Scuff Mark Remover
- Soap Scum Remover
- Rust Remover
- Hard Water Remover
- Germs Remover

Application/Usage:Multi Surface
Features:

- Deodorize
- Residue-free
- Disinfectant

**Physical Characteristics**

---

Product Color:Amber
**Miscellaneous**

---

Recycled:No
Assembly Required:No
Environmental Certification:EPA
Country of Origin:United States

Comment: Yes but I assume you are doing this for different products/texts so not really.

Comment: You may be better off using a proper text editor with Grep capability

Comment: Is "cleaner volume:" and "Scent:" always the start and end? If so you can use find() with mid().

Answer (score 0):

Given the bolding, I'll guess that Product Information is the key indicator, but that Scent is not universal.
So indeed as per @Solar_Mike, `=mid(find("Product Information",A1), 100)` would give the Product Information but plus more.
I suggest doing that formula first, and then any further processing in the next column.
Although I agree that Excel is not the most appropriate tool for this - @Heather_Mangin_Hairston: I'm intrigued how you get the data into Excel as one string?